# Error Copying Directory On Plugin Activation

Tags: plugins, activation, wp-filesystem

I am trying to copy directory using `WP_Filesystem API` with the method `copy_dir()` on plugin activation, but it is give me the following error message:

```
Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Filesystem_Direct::copy_dir()
in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxx.php on line 98
```

**Here is my codes:**

```
function sstssfb_activation_hook_vcheck() {
    delete_option(esc_attr("sstssfb_stop_showingvchecknotice"));

    /* INITIALIZE WPFilesytem */
    $access_type = get_filesystem_method();
    if($access_type === 'direct') {
        $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $creds = request_filesystem_credentials($url, '', false, false, array());
            // initialize the API
            if ( ! WP_Filesystem($creds) ) {
                // any problems and we exit
                return;
            }
            global $wp_filesystem;
    /* CREATE SSTSSFB_ASSETS DIRECTORY */
        if(!$wp_filesystem->is_dir(SSTSSFB_ASSET_DIR)) 
        {
            $wp_filesystem->mkdir(SSTSSFB_ASSET_DIR);
        }

    /* MOVE ADDITIONAL assets TO THAT (sstssfb_assets) DIRECTORY */
        // addons
        if(file_exists(SSTSSFBDIR_ADDONS_ORI))
        $wp_filesystem->copy_dir(SSTSSFBDIR_ADDONS_ORI, SSTSSFB_ASSET_DIR, true);
        $wp_filesystem->delete(SSTSSFBDIR_ADDONS_ORI);
        // themes
        if(file_exists(SSTSSFB_THEMEDIR_ORI))
        $wp_filesystem->copy_dir(SSTSSFB_THEMEDIR_ORI, SSTSSFB_ASSET_DIR, true);
        $wp_filesystem->delete(SSTSSFBDIR_ADDONS_ORI);
    }

    }
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, "sstssfb_activation_hook_vcheck");
```

What would be the problem here?

Comment: The problem here, honestly and respectfully, is that having a plugin copy files around the filesystem is almost always the wrong way to solve a problem and will always be subject to server permissions beyond your control and so may not work whatever your do. If you could explain the problem you are trying to solve rather than the broken method you are using to try to solve that problem perhaps someone will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

That was my fault!

The problem is `copy_dir` isn't a `WP_Filesystem` method, so it cannot be called as an instance of `WP_Filesystem` like this: `$wp_filesystem->copy_dir()`, but independently like this: `copy_dir("source", "destination")` after the WP_Filesystem() has already been called and setup.

Reference [copy_dir](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/copy_dir/)